# How, other than Hallow, can a place or object be consecrated or desecrated, so that it would be detected by Divine Sense or Detect Evil and Good?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, paladin

The paladin's [Divine Sense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#DivineSense) feature allows the paladin to

> ...detect the presence of any place or object that has been consecrated
>   or desecrated, as with the [*hallow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) spell.

Similarly, the spell [*detect evil and good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-evil-and-good) allows the caster to

> ...know if there is a place or object within 30 feet of you that has
>   been magically consecrated or desecrated.

How, other than via the spell *hallow*, can a place or object be consecrated or desecrated, so that it would be detected by Divine Sense or *detect evil and good*?

Question inspired by [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139288/can-a-paladins-divine-sense-detect-if-an-object-is-cursed), where we establish that Divine Sense cannot detect whether an object is cursed.

Comment: Is it important that the two detecting spells talk about different (i.e. one about magical and one about unscpecified) kinds of con/desecration? Or is that probably jsut variance in wording (since even the Divine Sense gives an example of a spell)?

Comment: Related: [Are there published effects of Consecrated (not Hallowed) Ground?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172073/23547)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### That's it

As far as I know, *hallow* is the only method to do so listed in the books:

> infuse an area... with holy (or unholy) power.

However, an area could be designated as either consecrated or desecrated by a GM. The Dungeon Master's Guide even has additional rules for desecrated ground on page 110:

> Some cemeteries and catacombs are imbued with the unseen traces of ancient evil...
>
> Undead standing on desecrated ground have advantage on all saving throws.
>
> A vial of holy water purifies a 10-foot-square area of desecrated ground when sprinkled on it, and a *hallow* spell purifies desecrated ground within its area.

One such area a GM may consider to be consecrated is a region affected by the *temple of the gods* spell (even though it is not explicitly called out as such).

Answer (score 2):

### How PCs can do it

*Hallow*, *Wish* or Divine Intervention by a Cleric.

### How NPCs can do it

However the DM wants - NPCs don’t use the same playbook as PCs.