# Are there published effects of Consecrated (not Hallowed) Ground?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

## Consecrated Ground, as distinct from Hallowed Ground, likely exists

The paladin's *divine sense* ability, and the *detect good and evil* spell, presuppose the existence of both consecrated and desecrated ground.  The paladin ability further suggests one way to create them.

> you also detect the presence of any place or object that has been consecrated or desecrated, as with the *hallow* spell.

By saying "as with" the *hallow* spell, rather than "by" the *hallow* spell, it is implied that there are other ways to consecrate or desecrate ground.  This is further implied by the strict size and shape permitted by the *hallow* spell but with the DMG description of desecrated ground allowing it to be "of any size".

Both the spell and the ability reveal that objects rather than areas may be consecrated or desecrated as well, an effect that is not brought about by the *hallow* spell.

Thus it is clearly established that while the *hallow* spell is one way to produce consecrated or desecrated ground, it is not the only way.

## I cannot find any description of the effects of consecrated ground (or a consecrated item) beyond that it can be detected

The DMG describes the only effect of desecrated ground as

> Undead standing on desecrated ground have advantage on all saving throws

which is noticeably weaker than the effects of *hallow*.  There is no description that I can find of the effects of consecrated ground (independent of *hallow*), or of consecrated and desecrated items.

**Question:  Is there any existing description of the effects of consecrated ground that I have missed?**

Related: [How, other than Hallow, can a place or object be consecrated or desecrated, so that it would be detected by Divine Sense or Detect Evil and Good?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139323/how-other-than-hallow-can-a-place-or-object-be-consecrated-or-desecrated-so-t)

The related question asks whether ground can be consecrated or desecrated without the use of the *hallow* spell.  I am not asking that; I am assuming that it can.  I am asking if there is any published description of what the effects would be of ground that is consecrated but not hallowed.

Reference to means of creating consecrated ground in other editions is not a good answer.  Designer notes and commentary outside of official publications hinting at intent or future releases are acceptable.

Comment: You're asking two questions here. The first one was already asked and answered: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139323/how-other-than-hallow-can-a-place-or-object-be-consecrated-or-desecrated-so-t Maybe you should consider the information there and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @Anagkai Thank you for the link, but that is not my question.  That question asks HOW something could be consecrated without Hallow.  My question presupposes that it COULD be, and asks WHAT the effects would be if it were.

Comment: I think, after reading these comments and then the question again, can your question be summarised as "Are there rules for consecrated ground that I've missed, since there are already rules for desecrated ground, and either way, would I mess up Curse of Strahd by adding in my homebrew rules for consecrated ground"? If I've got that right, you definitely want to split that up into two questions. Both are good questions, but not in the same post...

Comment: Consider also that an answer to the first question saying "sure, the rules for consecrated ground are in this other book here..." might significantly affect your second question, since you might decide not use your homebrew rules if it turns out there are official rules for consecrated ground, and which rules you use might affect how it may or many not affect Curse of Strahd... Hence I'd also recommend saving your second question until after you've got a satisfactory answer to the first, but that's just me. Either way, definitely should be split into two questions...

Comment: I see now, how your question is different from the one I found. Stating this in your question might be useful, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There do not appear to be any rules for consecrated ground outside of the [*hallow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) spell

As you have noted, there is an entry in the DMG (p. 110) on Desecrated Ground, the full text of which is:

> Some cemeteries and catacombs are imbued with unseen traces of ancient evil. An area of desecrated ground can be any size, and a *detect evil and good* spell cast within range reveals its presence.
>
> Undead standing on desecrated ground have advantage on all saving throws.
>
> A vial of holy water purified a 10-foot-square area of desecrated ground when sprinkled on it, and a *hallow* spell purifies desecrated ground within its area.

Given that these appear under the section Wilderness Hazards, it stands to reason that consecrated ground would not be considered  hazardous (unless you're evil, I suppose, but generally the assumption in D&D is that you're going up against the evil guys, though not always), so it makes sense that such a thing would not appear listed under this section.

However, it appears that there is no mention of consecrated ground throughout the DMG, and I know of no other book that mentions consecrated or desecrated ground (excluding those that refer to the DMG, such as the two occurrences of desecrated ground from *Curse of Strahd*<sup>1</sup>) outside of the *hallow* spell. Whilst it makes sense that if there is desecrated ground that can exist outside of the *hallow* spell, there should be such a thing as consecrated ground, but no such rules for that seems to exist.

---

<sup>1</sup> Will-O'-Wisp random encounter, p. 33, and area K67, p. 78.