# Material components for Commune spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, spell-components

The spell [*Commune*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/commune) specifys

> (incense and a vial of holy or unholy water)

obviously, holy water and incense have a definition but I couldn't find a definition or cost for "unholy water". Since it is assumed that a component pouch/focus ignores material components without a GP cost, would you have to pay for the incense and holy water?

[What is "unholy water"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108151/what-is-unholy-water)  related to the definition of unholy water however no RAW answer

Comment: I am not sure what the question is: are you asking if you have to pay for the incense and for holy water or are you asking what is unholy water?

Comment: @Eddymage I am asking if you have to pay for incense and holy/unholy water I attached the related because it might help find a cost for unholy water

Comment: Are you just asking what is unholy water and how much does it cost to buy?

Comment: @NautArch that was covered by the related question, I wanted to know if any of the materials had a cost and unholy water was one of them I wanted to clarify incase the others were different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Welcome to roleplaying with spell components.

As written, *a component pouch or a focus replace all of these components at no cost to the caster*:

> Casting some spells requires particular objects, specified in parentheses in the component entry. A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.

Since no cost is specified for the components of *commune*, either a focus or component pouch can replace these components without concern for if you have gone through roleplaying of finding these things. The idea here is that these things are standard fare for clerics, and any cleric would keep these things in their component pouch anyway.

That said, material components without cost provide an *optional roleplaying  experience* for the caster. If you want (or if your DM requires it), it can be fun to keep track of these things, or to roleplay the interactions necessary to obtain the incense and (un-)holy water. But to be clear, *these interactions are not required by the rules*, but may be required by your DM.